# add address to apple map

Tags: objective-c, ios6-maps, apple-maps

any one know how to add an address to apple map,

for example if I want to add this address "Rickmansworth, Hertfordshire WD3, Regno Unito" to map, how can I do that? I do not have latitude or longitude.

I searched in google, I did not find anything useful.

Can anyone help me?

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to geocode the address into geographic coordinates. Use one of the geocoding services, like [geonames](http://www.geonames.org/export/web-services.html). After getting results from geocoding service, you have to parse them and display as `MKAnnotationView`s on your `MKMapView`